# Datasets and Memory leaks

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-management, memory-leaks, dataset

I am trying to figure out the best way to use a `DataSet`/`DataTable` and cleaning up properly afterwards.

I am a little puzzled as to what causes memory to be released. I tested my theory with a  test application where I populated the same `DataTable` multiple times in a loop and looking at Windows' Task Manager for the memory footprint after 3 forced GC collects.

What I found is that:

1. If I did not call `Clear` or `Dispose`, or set the `DataTable` variable to `Nothing`, the final memory consumption in Task Manager was about 30k.
2. If I just set the variable to `Nothing` inside the loop, the final memory was about 15k.
   Question: Why does setting the variable to `Nothing` make a difference?
3. If I called only the `Dispose` method inside the loop, the final memory was about 19k.
4. If I called only `Clear` inside the loop, the final memory was about 16.5k. In fact, it did not change even after the `GC.Collect`.

I would really appreciate if someone can share what is the best way to use and cleanup `DataSet`s when no longer needed.

Sample code is shown below.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient;
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Test()

        GC.Collect()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.Collect() 'Throw in one more 
    End Sub


    Private Sub Test()
        Dim oDA As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing
        Dim oConn As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim oCommand As SqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim ods As DataSet = Nothing
        Dim oDt As DataTable = Nothing
        Try
            oConn = New SqlConnection("Server=Myserv;Database=myDB;UserId=myuserid;Password=mypassword;")
            oCommand = New SqlCommand("Select  * from Users", oConn)
            oConn.Open()
            ods = New DataSet

            oDA = New SqlDataAdapter(oCommand)

            For i As Integer = 0 To 50
                oDA.Fill(ods)
                oDt = ods.Tables(0)
                'oDt.Clear()
                'oDt.Dispose()
                oDt = Nothing
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            ods.Clear()
            ods = Nothing
            oConn.Close()
            oDA = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: I am looking for best practices for managing memory of `DataSet`s and/or `DataTable`s that are passed around, where the creating method is not necessarily tasked with cleaning up the memory. Also, why does setting an object/variable to `Nothing` within a function performs differently than just letting it go out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to "cleanup" your data would be to switch to a [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) for anything which implements `IDisposable`<sup>1</sup>. Once you implement this pattern you will have the most reasonable memory usage *for the data structures you have designed*.

```vb
Using oConn As New SqlConnection("Server=Myserv;Database=myDB;UserId=myuserid;Password=mypassword;")
    oConn.Open()
    Using oCommand As New SqlCommand("Select  * from Users", oConn)
        ' other code as needed, wrap IDisposable in Using...EndUsing
    End Using
End Using
```

This does not guarantee that your data structures themselves will be memory efficient, just that they will hold onto resources for only as long as necessary.

<sub>1. Yes, you sometimes cannot use one, but if you work off the premise that it is wrong not to use the using-statement, you'll be better off.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where possible I am changing them to use this "Using" pattern. But in a lot of cases the dataset or datatable is being passed around and the creator is not neccessarily tasked with disposing. My question is more specific about datasets and datatables that are passed around. Sorry I was not clear in my question originally. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

"And why does setting somthing to nothing within a function perform differently than just letting it go out of scope?"

You have accessed the somthing, so it is not eligible for GC before then.

When GC occurs is a bit non-deterministic: apparently it schedules its next invocation depending on several factors (cite: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-33-CLR-GC-Part-1 (a video)).

Comment: But I am explicitly calling GC.Collect thrice after the function that contains the following loop has returned. For i As Integer = 0 To 50 oDA.Fill(ods) oDt = ods.Tables(0) 'oDt.Clear() 'oDt.Dispose() oDt = Nothing Next . So the variable oDt is getting reused 50 times within the loop. Once a new object is assigned to the variable, that should be as good as setting that variable to nothing. But that does not seem to be the case here and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use any resource that has to be released after use, including DataTable or Dataset is by using keyword Using whenever possible. If not possible to use Using keyword,you should do something equivalent to Using keyword  like:
try
{
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
}
Finally
{
  object.dispose()
}

According msdn,any object that implements IDisposable should free resource using dispose method.Since both Dataset and 
DataTable inherits from MarshalByValueComponent which implements IDisposable, so it is better to call dispose method. If there
is any resource that does not implement IDisposable method then you can implement IDisposable interface and override dispose
method and do resource cleaning in dispose method. By setting DataSet or DataTable to null, you are simply removing the 
reference which will finally be collected by Garbage Collector. But using dispose method is better approach. You do not have 
to explicitly call GC.Collect method because Garbage collector is usually running in the background and whenever memory
falls below certain threshold (which is determined by compiler), it will free the memory used by those resources. For more information Please 
refer to Garbage Collection(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx)